# How do I count comparisons in a Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, node.js, tree

I have a class for binary nodes, a binary tree, and a binary search tree, they contain your basic tree functions, like find node, add node, remove node, get height, getnumberof nodes, and others like that. I tried to add a new function that counts the number of comparisons for finding a certain a certain node in the tree, but I've confused myself. The best I was able to do is check if the node was in the tree, but I can't figure out how to have the counter increment with each comparison. The method I'm trying to do is just difficult to translate into the code I have now. I just don't think I'm doing this right. If someone could help me out with this, I'd really apreciate it.

```
int counter = 0;
template<class ItemType>
ItemType BinarySearchTree<ItemType>::IsInTree(BinaryNode<ItemType>* 
BinTreePtr, const ItemType& item)
{
BinaryNode<ItemType>* tmp = BinTreePtr;
counter++;

if (tmp == NULL) {
    printf("Number of comparisons: \n", counter);
    return 1;
}
else {
    counter++;
    if (&tmp->getItem == item) 
    {
        printf("Number of comparisons: \n", counter);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        counter++;
        if (item < &tmp->g)
            return IsInTree(tmp->leftChildPtr, item);
        else
            return IsIntree(tmp->rightChildPtr, item);
    }
}   
}




int main(){
BinarySearchTree<string>* tree1Ptr = new BinarySearchTree<string>();

tree1Ptr->add("10");
tree1Ptr->add("20");
tree1Ptr->add("30");
tree1Ptr->add("40");
tree1Ptr->add("50");
tree1Ptr->add("60");
tree1Ptr->add("70");
tree1Ptr->add("80");


counter = 0;
tree1Ptr->IsInTree(tree1Ptr, "10");
}
```

Comment: wrap your comparisons in a function and increment a static counter each time the function is called

Comment: There is a [std::count_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) function for built-in containers.

Answer (score 2):

Initialise the counter value to 1 and increment counter before every comparison inside the condition to if statement

```
if (tmp == NULL) {
    printf("Number of comparisons: \n", counter-1);
    return 1;
}
else {
    if (counter++ && &tmp->getItem == item) 
    {
        printf("Number of comparisons: \n", counter-1);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (counter++ && item < &tmp->g)
            return IsInTree(tmp->leftChildPtr, item);
        else
            return IsIntree(tmp->rightChildPtr, item);
    }
}
```

counter-1 will give you the count, hope this helps

Comment: or you could initialise to 0, and then there's no need for the -1 everywhere?